# List is printing datetime.datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime

I have a result list that contains something like

```
[(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),), (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)]
```

How does one print it like 2013-01-01 00:01:14.000 , 2013-01-01 01:33:50.000 or a readable format.

I have tried printing them in string

```
import datetime
...
for date in results:
    print (str(date))
```

This prints

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),)
(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1, 14),), (datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 1, 33, 50),)]` is a list where each element is a 1-element tuple.

You are printing the tuple rather than the datetime within at the first position, `print(str(date[0]))` to get the actual value.`

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the datetime object out of the tuple, for it to be printed in string format.

```
>>> for each in results:
...     print(each[0])
...
2013-01-01 00:01:14
2013-01-01 01:33:50
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the tuple to string like:

```
str(datetime_object)
```